# can we take user input using python for mysql table values?

Tags: python, mysql, database-connectivity

> **I tried taking input,but its showing error.**

**raise errors.ProgrammingError(**

**ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement**

A part of code that i tried,

`#D_O_B

```
import datetime
 year = int(input('Enter birth year'))
 month = int(input('Enter birth month'))
 day = int(input('Enter birth day'))
 D_O_B = datetime.date(year, month, day)
 
 #Age
 A=int(input("Enter age"))
sql = """INSERT INTO PLAYER_DETAILS(
   Name,DATE_OF_BIRTH ,Age ,Federation ,Elo_RATING ,Title)
   VALUES ( %s,%d ,(%d %b %y), %s,%d , %s)"""

 val = (N,D_O_B,A,Fed,RATING,T)
 cursor.execute(sql, val)

 db.commit()
```

Comment: Use `%s` for all the placeholders.  Also what is the sub-expression `(%d %b %y)` supposed to do?

Comment: The error message simply tells that the number of place-holders is larger than the number of variables that you feed into the string. That is even true: 8 > 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pyodbc
```

pyodbc is open source odbc driver for python will allow you to connect sql,
Connect with

```
import pyodbc    
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=testdb;UID=me;PWD=pass')
```

then Create Cursor

```
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

and then create query like you do in sql query and wherever you want to use user input , replace it with **?** add second argument of execute as **array** and in array put respective values

```
cursor.execute("""
    select user_id, user_name
      from users
     where last_logon < ?
       and bill_overdue = ?
""", [datetime.date(2001, 1, 1), 'y'])
```

you can pass multiple argument if you dont want to use array as second argument but it also should be respective

```
cursor.execute("insert into products(id, name) values (?, ?)", 'pyodbc', 'awesome library')
```

and do commit after insert update or delete

```
cnxn.commit()
```

you found more here in official docs [Getting Started](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started)

Comment: and for taking date do something like this   year = int(input('Enter a year'))
month = int(input('Enter a month'))
day = int(input('Enter a day'))
date1 = datetime.date(year, month, day)